I can't access a cloudfront resource from within AWS
I have a lambda function that loads remote images and converts them.
When the image is on CloudFront, Lambda cannot access the image as it receives no response.
The image URL is correct as it works from my PC. The URL is of type https://example.cloudfront.net/path/to/image.jpg
The CloudFront page is not mine, I access it publicly.

Does the Lambda function run correctly if the URL is not pointing to CloudFront?

@JohnRotenstein yes
